# Are http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/ and deb.debian.org one and the same service?

Tags: debian, apt, etc

Sometime back, I had noticed that `httpredir.debian.org` no longer works or works a bit weirdly. I started using `cdn-fastly.debian.org` . This is how my /etc/apt/sources.list is setup currently -

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux buster-DI-alpha2 _Buster_ - Official Snapshot amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20171205-15:32]/ buster main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux buster-DI-alpha2 _Buster_ - Official Snapshot amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20171205-15:32]/ buster main

       #### Debian buster #########
        deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free

    deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
    deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main

       #### Debian unstable #########
    deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian unstable contrib non-free
    deb-src http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian unstable contrib non-free

        #### Debian experimental #########
    deb http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib
    deb-src http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib

       ##### Debian Debug packages #######
    deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ buster-debug main
    deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ unstable-debug main
    deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ experimental-debug main

      ######## Third party repos #######
    deb https://riot.im/packages/debian/ stretch main

      ########## Non-free ########
    #deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free
```

Then saw a reddit comment https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/69z49p/sources_list_httpredirdebianorg_now_redirects_to/ as well as `http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/` which seems to confirm the change. Does anybody know why the change was done. AFAIK Debian does most things in-house.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org` and `deb.debian.org` are part of the same *service*, but they’re not the same. The latter serves [two purposes](http://deb.debian.org/): its DNS records contain SRV records which allow `apt` to find mirrors (since Stretch), and it hosts a web server which will redirect `apt` to an appropriate host if necessary. The former is Fastly’s CDN for the Debian mirror network. The end result of using either in `sources.list` is the same; using `deb.debian.org` involves an extra step but is possibly more future-proof.

This particular service is sponsored by Fastly and Amazon CloudFront. All of Debian’s mirrors are sponsored in one way or another; [the list of sponsors is public](https://www.debian.org/mirror/sponsors.html). All `debian.org` services are official Debian services.